# Como não logar ações de um IP específico no Nginx?

Tags: nginx

Estou recebendo no IP do meu VPS milhares de conexões deste IP:

51.15.76.184 - - [17 / Dec / 2017: 16: 31: 17 -0200] "CONNECT portal.geniptv.com:8080 HTTP / 1.1" 400 172 "-" "-

A conexão já está bloqueada (erro 400), mas meu arquivo access.log em /var/log/nginx está ficando com gigabytes de tamanho por dia.

Como e onde eu paro de guardar logs desse IP acima especificamente?

Meu sitema é Debian 8 com ISPconfig 3.1 e Nginx.

Muito obrigado desde já

Answer (score 1):

É possível utilizando uma **[condição](https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/depth/ifisevil/)** e desabilitando o **[access_log](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_log_module.html#access_log)** do Nginx.

Para isso basta abrir o arquivo */etc/nginx/sites-available/default* e adicione o código abaixo.

```
location ~ /(.*)$ {
    if ( $remote_addr = "51.15.76.184" ) {
        access_log off;
    }
}
```

Comment: Prezado Valdeir,
Muito obrigado pela resposta.
Adicionei o bloco de código tanto no /etc/nginx/sites-available/default como no /etc/nginx/nginx.conf e mesmo assim continua logando.

O que devo fazer?

Comment: Você está reiniciando o servidor? `sudo nginx -s reload`

Comment: Prezado Valdeir,
Bom e muito obrigado pela resposta.
Eu reiniciei o servidor e coloquei aquele bloco de código mas mesmo assim continuei recebendo milhares de acessos por hora.

O que resolveu foi uma recomendação do meu servidor VPS veesp.com que me disse que não há como bloquear logging de um IP específico, mas que eu poderia banir o IP no  iptables. Fiz o passo abaixo e agora parou de logar.

`iptables -A INPUT -s 51.15.76.184/32 -i eth0 -j DROP`

Se mais alguém tiver esse problema, esta é a solução

Answer (score 1):

Prezado Valdeir,
Bom e muito obrigado pela resposta.
Eu reiniciei o servidor e coloquei aquele bloco de código mas mesmo assim continuei recebendo milhares de acessos por hora.

O que resolveu foi uma recomendação do meu servidor VPS veesp.com que me disse que não há como bloquear logging de um IP específico, mas que eu poderia banir o IP no  iptables. Fiz o passo abaixo e agora parou de logar.

`iptables -A INPUT -s 51.15.76.184/32 -i eth0 -j DROP`

Se mais alguém tiver esse problema, esta é a solução